# How to get multiple rows from a column in efficient way?

Tags: matlab, rows

(Want an efficient alternative for the following Matlab code.) I want to obtain a matrix 'data' of size (N-60*60) from the below mentioned Matlab code. With for-loop and N with a very large value, it takes high computational time. Could someone please recommend the faster way to obtain the data matrix.

```
N=10000;
a = randn(N,1);
order = 60;
for i=order:length(a)
    data(i-order+1,:) = a([i:-1:i-order+1])';
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an executable example.  `sysID_data` is undefined. Please see how to create a [mcve] and then [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: @SardarUsama Thank you for your response. I have modified the code accordingly. Just looking for an alternative solution for the presented Matlab code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by high computational time? It runs in less than a second here.

Comment: @SardarUsama Thank you for your solution. Surely, I will try with initializing the variable `data` as per your suggestion.

Comment: Typo in previous comment, I meant `data = zeros(9941,60);` or in general: `data=zeros(length(a)-order+1,order);`

Comment: @SardarUsama Thank you for your solution. Surely, I will try with initializing the variable `data` as per your suggestion. Actually, I am storing the rows in `data` which is extracted from `a` variable. Eventually, the dimension of `data` would be (9941*60). Since I am not a frequent user of this forum, I will follow the guidelines as per [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]

Comment: @Trilarion Actually, I am working with very large N, then obtaining 'data' matrix takes time.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `N` that you're dealing with?

Comment: At times the value is around 0.5 million to 1 million (for my different data sets).

Answer (score 0):

As Sardar said pre-allocating data will give you the largest improvement. However you can also remove the for loop using clever indexing. The comments should explain most of what I did.

```
n = 1e6;
% Modified a to be a incrementing list to better understand how data is
% constructed
a = (1:n)';
order = 60;

%% Original code with pre allocation added
data = zeros(n-order+1, order);
for i = order:length(a)
    data(i-order+1,:) = a([i:-1:i-order+1])';
end

%% Vectorized code
% The above code was vectorized by building a large array to index into
% the a vector with.

% Get the indicies of a going down the first column of data
%   Went down the column instead of across the row to avoid a transpose
%   after the reshape function
idx = uint32(order:n);

% As we go across the columns we use the same indexing but -1 as we move to
% the right so create the simple offset using 0:-1:1-order. Then expand to
% the correct number of elements using kron
offset = kron(uint32(0:-1:1-order), ones(1, n-order+1, 'uint32'));

% Replicate the column indexing for how many columns we have and add the
% offset
fullIdx = repmat(idx, 1, order) + offset;

% Then use the large indexing array to get all the data as a large vector
% and then reshape it to the matrix
data2 = reshape(a(fullIdx), n-order+1, order);

% idx, offset, and fullIdx will take up a fair amount of memory so it is
% probably best to clear them
clear idx offset fullIdx;

assert(isequal(data, data2));
```

Note: The use of uint32 is not strictly necessary however it does save on memory usage and does give a small performance improvement.